# double quotation mark inside url and WebBrowser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri

i got a decent problem with the WebBrowser control in windows phone 8. i have registered a custom uriparser that allows to send commands via `window.location.href = "myprotocoll://processCommand(17, 'jscriptcallback', '{\"data0\":\"hello\"}')"` however it works great except if i start to add double quotationmarks, like in my example. `({"data0":"hello"})` what becomes necessary if i want to send a json string. there is no error output no exception in my app nothing if you try to navigate to that url via window.location.href just nothing will happen. i think this is a very strange behavoir.

**My UriParser:**

```
public class MyUriParser : UriParser
{
    public MyUriParser()
    {

    }

    protected override string GetComponents(Uri uri, UriComponents components, UriFormat format)
    {
        return "";
    }
    protected override bool IsWellFormedOriginalString(Uri uri)
    {
        return true;
    }
    protected override void InitializeAndValidate(Uri uri, out UriFormatException parsingError)
    {
        parsingError = null;
    }
    protected override bool IsBaseOf(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri)
    {
        return false;
    }
    protected override string Resolve(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri, out UriFormatException parsingError)
    {
        parsingError = null;
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Registered via:**

```
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme(SCHEMENAME_0))
    UriParser.Register(new MyUriParser(), SCHEMENAME_0, 80);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation marks are probably terminating the string, causing odd behavior. When using quotation marks that you want to stay inside a string, use '\' before the quotation marks so they don't end the string. In your case, you'd want to do something like:

`window.location.href = "myprotocoll://processCommand(17, 'jscriptcallback', '{\"data0\":\"hello\"}')"`

Comment: That was just a typo while creating the post. but thanks mate. ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Other than that I sadly don't have much insight to offer. Good luck though.